# Airflow dagbag_import_timeout - use subdag ?

Tags: python, airflow

I am using Airflow 1.8.0 in LocalExecutor mode.
I have had problems recently with some DAGs having many tasks: the tasks were staying in state = 'queued' but never starting because of a timeout error during dagbag import.

```
[2018-08-08 00:10:50,388] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/mydag.py
[2018-08-08 00:10:51,187] {models.py:167} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /opt/airflow/dags/mydag.py
[2018-08-08 00:12:57,790] {timeout.py:37} ERROR - Process timed out
[2018-08-08 00:12:57,791] {models.py:266} ERROR - Failed to import: /opt/airflow/dags/mydag.py
```

The solutions I had found to fix that were to increase dagbag_import_timeout and to split the DAG into smaller DAGs. 
But I am wondering if using the subdag operator would help. Would Airflow only try to import each subdag separately or would it still try to load the whole thing and give me the same errors ?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of your DAG code, 2 minutes for a DAG import is extremely slow and it is likely you are doing something resource intensive in your top-level DAG code.

Comment: Actually the DAG code is very easy, it is just a creating a DAG with a for loop to create about 20 branches of 7 tasks each. But there is nothing else querying something or loading a file for example. When I do  python mydag.py  it executes in 1-2s.

Comment: But one thing I noticed is that before I had a problem with many 'airflow scheduler' processes (700+) running at the same time because of a wrong configuration of supervisord. Maybe this was querying too much stuff in the metadata leading to this timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, I faced the same issue. After upgrading my VM, I also faced the same issue. Here are the commands I ran.

```
airflow db init
airflow webserver
```

However, it still displayed dagbag_import_timeout error. There were many ways I tried, but none worked.

I then found the following command.

> airflow scheduler

This solved my problem. I hope this will solve your problem.

It is sometimes not coming due to the same error I was experiencing. The airflow website also provides official links you should check out.

[Reducing Dag Complexity](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#reducing-dag-complexity)

[Top Level Python Code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html#top-level-python-code)